# php database class

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

I am trying to manage my database connections and queries through OOP in PHP, and I'm not great at it. I know I'm reinventing the wheel, but that's the way I like it :)

I am using three classes, including a [SQL parser](http://www.tehuber.com/article.php?story=20081016164856267) I haven't done myself. My implementation returns an object when a new connection is created. Programmer should create a new query instance (one instance per SQL statement) through this database object. My question is: how can I get my query class to be only invocable from the database class?

I'm pasting a resume of my classes and the implementation below. Feel free to let me know how bad it is. Thanks!

```
    class genc_db_parser
    {
        /* See at http://www.tehuber.com/article.php?story=20081016164856267
        returns an array with indexed values ('select','from','where','update',...) when they are available */
    }
    class genc_database
    {
        public $db; /* The database connection */
        public $signature; /* Unique signature for the connection */
        public static $instances = array(); /* Array of references to connection */
        public static function error($e,$sql)
        {
            /* Errors */
        }
        private static function singleton($cfg,$inst)
        {
            $signature = sha1(serialize($cfg));
            if ( isset($cfg['host'],$cfg['user'],$cfg['pass'],$cfg['db'],$cfg['engine']) )
            {
                foreach ( self::$instances as $obj )
                {
                    if ( $obj->signature == $signature )
                        return $obj->db;
                }
                try
                    { $db = new PDO($cfg['engine'].':host='.$cfg['host'].';dbname='.$cfg['db'], $cfg['user'], $cfg['pass']);    }
                catch (PDOException $e)
                    { self::error($e); }
                if ( $db )
                {
                    $t = self::$instances;
                    array_push($t,$inst);
                    return $db;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        function __construct($cfg=array())
        {
            if ( isset($cfg['host'],$cfg['user'],$cfg['pass'],$cfg['db']) )
                $cfg['engine'] = isset($cfg['engine']) ? $cfg['engine'] : 'mysql';
            else
                $cfg = array(
                    'host' => GEN_DB_HOST,
                    'user' => GEN_DB_USER,
                    'pass' => GEN_DB_PASS,
                    'db' => GEN_DATABASE,
                    'engine' => GEN_DB_ENGINE
                );
            if ( isset($cfg['host'],$cfg['user'],$cfg['pass'],$cfg['db'],$cfg['engine']) )
            {
                if ( $this->db = self::singleton($cfg,$this) )
                {
                    $this->signature = sha1(serialize($cfg));
                    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    if ( $cfg['engine'] == 'mysql' )
                    {
                        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
                        $this->db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public function query($sql)
        {
            return new genc_query($sql,&$this);
        }
    }
    class genc_query
    {
        private $sql, $conn, $db, $res, $sequences, $num;
        function __construct($sql_statement,$db)
        {
            $sql_statement = trim($sql_statement);
            if ( !empty($sql_statement) )
            {
                $this->sql = $sql_statement;
                $this->conn = &$db;
                $this->db = &$db->db;
                $this->analyze();
            }
        }
        private function analyze()
        {
            if ( $this->sql !== null )
            {
                $this->sequences = genc_db_parser::ParseString($this->sql)->getArray();
            }
        }
        private function execute()
        {
            if ( $this->res === null )
            {
                $this->res = false;
                if ( isset($this->sequences['select']) )
                {
                    try
                        { $this->res = $this->db->query($this->sql); }
                    catch (Exception $e)
                        { genc_database::error($e,$this->sql); }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                        { $this->res = $this->db->exec($this->sql); }
                    catch (Exception $e)
                        { genc_database::error($e,$this->sql); }
                }
            }
            return $this->res;
        }
        public function count()
        {
            if ( $this->num === null )
            {
                $req = false;
                $this->num = false;
                if ( isset($this->sequences['select']) )
                {
                    $sql = genc_db_parser::ParseString($this->sql)->getCountQuery();
                    try
                        { $req = $this->db->query($sql); }
                    catch (Exception $e)
                        { genc_database::error($e,$sql); }
                    if ( $req )
                        $this->num = $req->fetchColumn();
                }
            }
            return $this->num;
        }
        public function get_result()
        {
            if ( $this->execute() )
                return $this->res;
            return false;
        }
        public function get_row()
        {
            $this->execute();
            if ( $this->res && isset($this->sequences['select']) )
                return $this->res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return false;
        }
        /* Other functions working on the result... */
    }
```

Implementation

```
    /* db is the database object */
    $db = new genc_database();
    /* concurrent connections can be opened. However giving twice the same argument will return the same corresponding opened connection */
    $db2 = new genc_database(array('host'=>'localhost','user'=>'myname','pass'=>'mypass','db'=>'mydb');
    /* $db->query($sql) will create a query object ($q) attached to this database */
    $q = $db->query(sprintf("
        SELECT id,name,modified
        FROM users
        WHERE id_account = %u",
        $id
    ));
    /* $q->count() will return the number of rows returned by the query (through a COUNT), and without taking the limit into account */
    echo $q->count();
    /* $q->get_row will return the next row of the current recordset indexed by name */
    while ( $data = $q->get_row() )
        echo $data['id'].': '.$data['name'].'<br />';
    /* If we do another action than a select, functions ahead will not return an error but false */
    /* On other actions, just to execute the query, use get_result(), which will return the number of affected rows */
    $p = $db2->query("UPDATE user2 SET modified = NOW() WHERE id = 1");
    echo $p->get_result().'<br />';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Feel free to let me know how bad it is.

It's bad!

...

What?

You *asked*!

Okay, in all seriousness, it's not so much bad as it is *silly*.  You're *wrapping* PDO in another class.  If you want to add *more* functionality to PDO, you should be extending it instead.

> My question is: how can I get my query class to be only invocable from the database class?

PDO already does this during day to day operations.  When you [`prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) a query, it returns a [PDOStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object.  You can configure it to return another object ([via `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)) that extends PDOStatement instead.

If you want to pre-process the query using your parser, you'll need to *override* the [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), [`query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) and `prepare` methods in your class that extends PDO.  Once you've processed the query, you can call the parent method and return your extended statement class.

If you're worried about people invoking the statement class without going through `exec`/`query`/`prepare`, just keep in mind that no queries can be *executed* unless the statement knows how to access the database, and it won't be able to do that without the parent PDO object.

---

Also,

```
$q = $db->query(sprintf("
    SELECT id,name,modified
    FROM users
    WHERE id_account = %u",
    $id
));
```

This is downright absurd given the circumstances.  You have a PDO object here, there's no reason *not* to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [placeholders](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) here.  If you don't want to bind one variable at a time (and I don't blame you), that's what [`execute`'s optional array argument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) is for.

Comment: +1 and I'd give +7 if I could for taking time for a nice elaborated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I asked, so thanks! I didn't think of extending PDO, I see why that's better now. And you're right also I must say about the last point. Bad habit from a long time ago...